# Table Doesn't Exist Error When Java MVC app in Docker Container Try to Connect to MySQL in Another Container

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, docker, model-view-controller

I have a Java-Hibernate MVC web application that uses a mySql database. It works fine on my computer but doesn't work when I try to run it using docker containers. I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows Home because the latest version of Docker requires Windows Professional.

-------Please ignore class and function and database names in my code snippets below, I quickly changed the names to retain anonymity. I have carefully verified that in reality all the names are correct. ----------

I have an MVC web application running on Tomcat in one container and a mySql database running in the other. I think my application can connect to the database because I am able to load the home page in my web application in one of the Docker containers without error. But when I try to put something in one of the MySql tables I get the following error:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'no_visits.visitors' doesn't exist
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:353)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2168)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1489)
org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
com.horse.novisit.dao.VisitDAOImpl.isVisit(isVisitImpl.java:79)
com.horse.novisit.service.VisitServiceImpl.isVisit(isVisitImpl.java:67)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.isLongUrlInDB(Unknown Source)
com.horse.noToVisit.controller.visitController.postBigVisit(VisitController.java:47)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can connect to the container and poke around inside?

Comment: I went into the mysql container and the tables are there

Comment: is it possible that you misspelled table name like visitor instead of visitors or vice versa.

Comment: That's not the case. I am a busy person but I did spend what little time I have carefully going through my code. Any misspellings above are because I quickly changed the name of classes and functions to keep the code anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, yet. Just a way to help you troubleshoot.

When the container is running:

```
docker ps
```

Find the process id

```
docker exec -it theidgoeshere bash
```

That will get you a bash shell into the running docker process. From there you can examine the log files of the running processes. You might not have bash available but that command is very useful. Read here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

If this is all greek then I can point you to some more online material.

Comment: That's an expression I haven't seen heard for many years. I will try and take a look at the logs and see if that brings up anything helpful, but this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`docker network create -d bridge my-network`

`docker build -t my-mysqldb .`

`docker run -p 3306:3306  --network=my-network --name no-visit -itd  my-mysqldb`

`docker build -t spring-mvc-image .`

`docker run -p 8080:8080  --network=my-network --name spring-mvc-container -itd -e DATABASE_HOST=no-visit -e DATABASE_PORT=3306 -e DATABASE_NAME=no_visit -e DATABASE_USER=visitor -e DATABASE_PASSWORD=visitor spring-mvc-image`

And after this when you run `docker ps` it should show you both the containers in running state.

If problem still persists check the logs `docker logs no-visit`.

Comment: The names are fine. I quickly changed them on this forum to make my code anonymous and might have made a few typos.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The name of the database in the .sql script I was running turned out to be wrong.